# How can I include a hosted JS file with PyroCMS / Lex?

Tags: pyrocms, pyrocms-lex

To load files in my theme, I use `{{ theme:js file="bootstrap.min.js" }}`. But what if I want to load something from a CDN like `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js`.

I tried `{{ theme:js file="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" }}` but that errors out.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link to it directly as you would normally without using an actual "tag." For example take a look at this header partial from the base theme of Pyro 2.2:

https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms/blob/2.2/develop/addons/shared_addons/themes/base/views/partials/header.html#L33

(note this example is a remote css file but, the same can be done with js files etc.)

Comment: I was hoping to stick with `Lex` if possible to keep my code consistent. So can I assume that it can't be done with `Lex`?

Comment: That would be the assumption for me as well though, I'm honestly not totally sure. I looked at the docs and didn't find any information on it.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you do that?!

I wrote `{{ theme:js }}` to help people not need to think about where their files were. If you are trying to include `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js` then you know where it is.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" />
```

That is all you need to do. Don't overthink it.